# counting atoms and lists in a list

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to write a function to calculate the number of atoms in the upper level of a list.  For example, if I have a  `'(a b ((a) c) e)`, it should return 3, meaning there are 3 atoms in the upper level.

I also want to make a function that counts the number of sub lists in the list.  The second function should count from every level upper and lower.  If we have `'(a ((b) s))`, it should return 1 if the sub list is in the upper level and 2 if the function counts from upper to lower level or any level of the list.

My code below counts the number of atoms in the list, which i do not want.  How can I fix it?
And how can code the other function?

```
(defun count-atoms(L)
  (cond
    ((null l) 0)
    ((atom l) 1)
    (t (+ (count-atoms (car l))
          (count-atoms (cdr l))))))
```

If I run the above code, let's say

```
(count-atoms '(a b ((a) c) e))
```

it gives me 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code recursively looks at each `(car l)` until it's an atom, so every item gets counted.

This should work:

```
(defun count-atoms(l)
  (cond
    ((null l) 0)
    (t (+ (cond
            ((atom (car l)) 1)
            (t 0))
          (count-atoms (cdr l))))))
```